# Suppressing warning on only one occurence

Tags: gcc

I am coding some OS code, that the compiler does not understand and in one of my function I do:

```
void kernel_getpid()
{
        register unsigned int r0 asm("r0") = current_pid;
}
```

So the compiler complains:

```
Warning: Variable "r0" is not used
```

How can I disable the warning only at this single point in the file?
I generally want to have these warnings so I do not want to turn them off globally but at this point it gets annoying as I cannot do anything about it.

Comment: Q: Why not just do the complete assignment in assembler?  This is ARM, isn't it?

Comment: Of course this might solve this special case but I would like a more general answer to the question, as this is not the first time that I stumble upon this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from version 4.2 but before 4.6 you can use the followings. Unforunatelly it turns off warnings from that point forward in the file.

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"
void kernel_getpid()
{
  register unsigned int r0 asm("r0") = current_pid;
}
```

For version 4.6 or later you can push and pop diagnostic flags, so you use the followings.

```
void kernel_getpid()
{
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"

  register unsigned int r0 asm("r0") = current_pid;
}
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

You can read more details in the GCC [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html) or in a tutorial about supressing GCC warnings [here](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/SuppressingGCCWarnings.html).